# Static PHP function not return value

Tags: php, yii

I have this function that does a select statement and returns the results. I can see the results coming in but my function is returning a null object.

```
public static function getMySteps($schema, $StepNum){
    $retVal = null;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM mysteps where id=" . $StepNum; 
    Yii::log($sql,'info','.getMySteps');
    $results = execSQL($schema, $sql);
    if (is_array($results) && count($results) > 0){
        $retVal = $results[0];
    }
     Yii::log("returning " . isset($retVal), "info", "getMySteps");

    return $retVal;
}
```

I am calling this function in another function

```
 $retval = self::getMySteps($mySchema, $myStepNum);
 Yii::log("step count found " . isset($retVal), "info", "nextStep");
```

When I'm looking at the logs I see

`returning 1`

`step count found`

Which means I getting results from the query but the function is return nothing.

Comment: You are using `$retval` and `$retVal`. You may want to change that.

Comment: Thank you!! you save me a lot of hours looking at this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to comment but I can't so right after you read this, I will delete the "answer".

Your variables do not match and this can happen often. One simple trick is to have your IDE or simple text editor highlight the variable currently selected in the text. I did your mistake once and lost a lot of time. So here's my little tip. :)

Edit : see this atom package as an example : https://atom.io/packages/highlight-selected

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11672807)

Comment: I did not have 50 rep at the time. Will remove this in due time.